# Does the age/timestamp of a transaction matter to a miner?

Tags: transactions, gas, mining, pending-transactions, timestamp

Up to now I know that miners choose transactions to be included in a block only based on their related transaction fees.

Does the *age* (i.e. *timestamp*) of a transaction play any role in the priority policy adopted by a miner?

Let's say that transaction `tx_a` has a transaction fee slightly lower than `tx_b`, but it has been created earlier than `tx_b`. Is there any chance for `tx_a` to be mined before `tx_b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. Until a transaction is mined, it remains in the mempool where it awaits to be picked by a miner either for gas fee or for MEV incentives. The timestamp of when the transaction is signed does not factor into any incentives.